# incorrect output from Debug.WriteLine("Put text here: {0}", myString)

Tags: c#, .net, string, logging, format

String.Format works fine with Debug.WriteLine if variable not of string type:

```
int myNumber = 1;
Debug.WriteLine("Put number here: {0}", myNumber);
```

**Correct Output with Non-String**

- Put number here: 1

But if variable is string:

```
string myString = "ShouldWork";
Debug.WriteLine("Put text here: {0}", myString);
```

**Incorrect Output with String**

- ShouldWork: Put text here: {0}

### Why?

Comment: @HansPassant: although I liked your comment better before you toned it down, +1: you could say that again!

Comment: I think it has something to do with an early implementation of [Conditional] not suppressing the argument expressions.  Couldn't find any evidence for it though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting [the wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x.aspx)...

You could work around that:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Put text here: {0}", myString, null/*dummy*/);
```

A good wrapper would be

```
public static void DebugFormat(string fmt, params object[] p)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(fmt, p); // this will select the right overload 
                              // ... due to typeof(p)==object[]
}

// ...
DebugFormat("Put text here: {0}", myString, null/*dummy*/);
int myNumber = 1;
DebugFormat("Put number here: {0}", myNumber);
```

Comment: Or use named arguments, if you're under C# 4.

Answer (score 3):

You are inadvertently calling a different overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x.aspx

For the desired behavior, you can use string concatenation:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Put text here: " + myString);
```

or a call to String.Format:

```
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format ("Put text here: {0}", myString));
```

Comment: Neither of those explains why they get the behaviour described. Also why should you have to use `String.Format()` when `Debug.WriteLine()` already supports it?

Comment: @Lankymart Did you follow the bit about the other overload, with the link to MSDN?

Comment: Of course I did! I understand the problem just think your suggestions are not a solution. `Debug.Print()` is definitely the best workaround for this issue (with named args a close second). Still think it's daft to give a method a conflicting overload when it's probably the most common use case though.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Put number here: {0}", 1));
```

Also, make sure that your Output option (drop down menu) in Visual Studio is set to Debug... It is not on by default in many cases.